# Angular Js: Get data from span and append in another span

Tags: angularjs

Hello everyone I am trying to learn Angular and I want to get data from a Span and append in another span. Please help me out fro there.
My code is here

```
<div ng-app="" >
<div>
      Name: <span ng-init="firstName='Ritu'">Ritu</span>
      Address: <span ng-init="address='Uttam Nagar'">Uttam Nagar</span>
      City: <span ng-init="city='West Delhi'">West Delhi</span>
      State: <span ng-init="state='Delhi'">Delhi</span>
pin: <span ng-init="pin='110045'">110045</span>
<button>Click and Show</button>
</div
```

And I want to show like that but after click on  show button

```
<p>Name <span ng-bind="firstName"></span></p>
<p>Address <span ng-bind="address"></span></p>
<p>City <span ng-bind="city"></span></p>
<p>State <span ng-bind="state"></span></p>
<p>pin <span ng-bind="pin"></span></p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: best to forget the ng-init and initialize data in controller ( $scope.firstName = )

Answer (score 0):

I created a plnkr that does what you would like to do . Check it out http://plnkr.co/edit/8xZik28CECenuPpLgdpq?p=preview
I used **ng-show** directive which results as **css display (block or none)** and you may use **ng-if** if you desire but **ng-if** has **performance** impact when used so many times , and you can find alternate ways of this I just wanted to give a quick move .

**the html part**

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
          Name: <span ng-init="firstName='Ritu'">Ritu</span>
          Address: <span ng-init="address='Uttam Nagar'">Uttam Nagar</span>
          City: <span ng-init="city='West Delhi'">West Delhi</span>
          State: <span ng-init="state='Delhi'">Delhi</span>
    pin: <span ng-init="pin='110045'">110045</span>
    <button data-ng-click="show=!show">Click and Show</button>
    <div ng-show="show">
    <p>Name <span ng-bind="firstName"></span></p>
<p>Address <span ng-bind="address"></span></p>
<p>City <span ng-bind="city"></span></p>
<p>State <span ng-bind="state"></span></p>
<p>pin <span ng-bind="pin"></span></p>
</div>
  </body>
```

**the app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.show=false;
});
```

Comment: Thank You Its Working as i want  :)

Answer (score 0):

At first, a lot of used `ng-init` directive commonly not best practice. [Take a look angular's advice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).
So that reason, I think initializing value have to be placed in controller.

Check it out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dqGlYR9ucuX0iuqH5nw1?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

**ng-init** is for having initial data, But it also gets unnecessary logic into the Template 
You can do the same Initializing in the Controller like:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
   firstName: 'Ritu',
   address: 'Uttam Nagar',
   city: 'West Delhi',
   state: 'Delhi',
   pin: '110045'
}
$scope.show=false;  });
```

And bind the **user** object in the view like:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      Name: <span>{{user.firstName}}</span>
      Address: <span>{{user.address}}</span>
      City: <span>{{user.city}}</span>
      State: <span>{{user.state}}</span>
      pin: <span>{{user.pin}}</span>
<button data-ng-click="show=!show">Click and Show</button>
<div ng-show="show">
<p>Name <span ng-bind="user.firstName"></span></p>
<p>Address <span ng-bind="user.address"></span></p>
<p>City <span ng-bind="user.city"></span></p>
<p>State <span ng-bind="user.state"></span></p>
<p>pin <span ng-bind="user.pin"></span></p>
</div>
</body>
```

This simplifies the Code and keeps the Template clean 
[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/139D99Fd3BpWkbqtavQ1?p=preview)